# Search in column datagridview return value coresponding value datadgridview vb.net

Tags: vb.net, search, datagridview

I have a `datagridview` in `vb.net` with three columns. In the first column, a product description, in the second column there is a product number and in the third column, a price is given.

I would like to search in a `datagridview` by product number and return the corresponding value in the prices column.

I can to search for  text in `datagridview`s, but I can't read the value of a corresponding cell such as the price cell.

```
Private Sub Button33_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button33.Click
    Dim rowindex As String
    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
        If row.Cells.Item("ITEM_ID").Value = TextBox5.Text Then
            rowindex = row.Index.ToString()

            Dim actie As String = row.Cells("PRICE").Value.ToString()
            MsgBox(actie)

        Else

            MsgBox("Item not found")

        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: This shouldn't be to difficult to solve, I just want to know how the datagridview gets the values and how you search through it.

Comment: see edit i did manage the following but my else keeps repeating for the amount of columns searched in..which if the item is not found would be quite anoying after 100+ columns

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Allright, thanks for the code update. Do this:

```
Private Sub Button33_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button33.Click
    Dim rowindex As String
    Dim found as Boolean = false
    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
        If row.Cells.Item("ITEM_ID").Value = TextBox5.Text Then
            rowindex = row.Index.ToString()
            found = true
            Dim actie As String = row.Cells("PRICE").Value.ToString()
            MsgBox(actie)
            Exit for
        End If
    Next
    If Not found Then
       MsgBox("Item not found")
    End if    
End Sub
```

What this does is that it loops through all the items. When it finds a match it sets found to true. If not item is found then "found" is false when the loop ends. And if "found" is false then you display "Item not found". Hope you understand, otherwise ask :)

Answer (score 1):

It works for me. Try this:

```
If TextBoxSearch.Text IsNot Nothing Then
    Dim IsItemFound As Boolean = False
    Dim ItemPrice As String
    DataGridView1.ClearSelection()
    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
        If row.Cells("ItemId").Value.ToString = TextBoxSearch.Text Then
            IsItemFound = True
            ItemPrice = row.Cells("ItemPrice").Value.ToString()
            row.Selected = True
            DataGridViewDetails.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = row.Index
            Exit For
        End If

        If Not IsItemFound Then
            MsgBox("Item not found")
        End If
    Next
End If
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it