# How to search in and edit Table by using DataGridView

Tags: sql, vb.net, winforms, datagridview

I have a SQL database with a table "Employees" in it (with large number of rows). By using DataGridView, I want to search for specific "Employee's Name" and change it's "Job". How can I achieve that. I'm using VB.net. Please Help Me.

Comment: by what method do you wish to search for said employee? if through the datagridview, do you mean that the datagridview should only show the record you're searching for? or the datatgridview should suddenly point out from the collection the employee you're referring to?

Comment: I want to search by any way, suppose the second way that you mentioned. The Important thing is when i find the specific row i want to editing it's data. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this will help but write a loop that goes through all the values if it finds a match its true if not it is false ,if found the item can be displayed in a textbox and edited 
if not a message is displayed saying "no match found"

the editing part can be done using a procedure that will update the value in your grid with what is entered

i can supply code for this if need be but i am unsure if this is what you wish 
and there is most likely a better way of doing it

Comment: Ghaz i found a previous question that might help i will give you the code as soon as possible i have a dead line on a project in 2 hours this link will take you to where a oak looped through to find a value see if you can modify it il give you the rest as soon as i can i apologize for the delay  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19223852/search-in-column-datagridview-return-value-coresponding-value-datadgridview-vb-n

Comment: ok still not done but where you able to modify the code and secondly do you know how a sql stored procedure works and how to call one Malky kid code would also work but if you wish to guard against sql injection use a proc

Answer (score 0):

you can loop through your grid, and check if the data you wish to edit exists using the For loop:

Supposing you are using a textbox as the input, and you use a label to hold the employee ID:

```
Dim EmpIDColumn as Integer = 'array number of your EmpID Column
Dim EmpNameColumn as Integer = 'The array number of the column where your EmpName is

Dim JobColumn as Integer = 'The array number of your job column
For each dr as Datagridviewrow in Datagridview1.Rows
    If dr.cells(EmpNameColumn).value = TxtSearchBox.text Then
      txtEmpJob.text = dr.cells(JobColumn).value
      lblEmpID.Text = dr.cells(EmpIDColumn).value
    End if
Next
```

**Okay,** so you've searched the record successfully. Next step (after editing the job, and even other details like the name) would be to update the record in the grid. Remember you set the lblEmpID's text to empID in the column? Use it to find the 
Record you wish to change in the grid using the same technique above!

```
Dim EmpIDColumn as Integer = 'array number of your EmpID Column
Dim EmpNameColumn as Integer = 'The array number of the column where your EmpName is

Dim JobColumn as Integer = 'The array number of your job column

 For each dr as Datagridviewrow in Datagridview1.Rows
    If dr.cells(EmpIDColumn).value = lblEmpID.text Then
       dr.cells(JobColumn).value = txtEmpJob.text
       dr.cells(EmpNameColumn).value = txtEmpName.text
        'then, type in here your SQL Query Update!
    End if
Next
```

Comment: Thank you @Malky.Kid, Now after modifying the code the data "that I changed" in DataGridView  are updated but the Database aren't updated, where is the problem.

Comment: Notice the part where I commented "Type in here your sql query update!"? you were supposed to put in there the SQL execute nonquery command for updating in there.